# question of probability and complex number

Tags: probability

$z$ and $w$ are complex numbers.
Let $z=5+12i$ and $|w|=13$. One of the $w$ numbers is chosen.  What is the probability of $|z-w|>13\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: I'm assuming you are choosing $w$ uniformly from a circle of radius 13. In this case, you need to find the length of a certain special arc on a circle of radius 13 centered at $5+12i$.

Answer (score 0):

This is only nominally a question about complex numbers.  On the complex plane, $z$ is plotted at $(5, 12)$, and the space that $w$ can be selected from is the circle centered at the origin, with radius $13$.  Note that $z$ is on that circle.  Assuming that $w$ is selected uniformly and randomly from that circle, the probability is then the portion of that circle that is more than $13\sqrt{3}$ distant from the point $z$.

Observe that the point $z$ itself is not special, other than it is on the circle.  In other words, the answer would be the same if $z$ were equal to $13$.  That may make it easier for you to visualize.